# More efficient approach than pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

In the code below, the objective is to, for each group as defined by `ID`, only keep the records that occur within a number of `DAYS` from the first record for that `ID` (the input data is sorted by `ID` and `TIME`).

I wonder if this is a good approach, or if there is a more efficient way to tackle this task. I have noticed that this is very slow with larger amounts of data.

```
df[df.groupby('ID').TIME.apply(lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.cumsum().fillna(0).abs())<=DAYS]
```

Note, I'm not expecting somebody to solve my situation. I merely want to discuss if there is a better approach than `df.groupby()`.

**EDIT**

Some sample data:

```
DAYS = 4

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'TIME': [
        np.datetime64('2020-01-01'),
        np.datetime64('2020-01-02'),
        np.datetime64('2020-01-09'),
        np.datetime64('2020-01-04'),
        np.datetime64('2020-01-06'),
        np.datetime64('2020-01-20')
    ]
})

df = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'TIME'], ascending=True)
```

Comment: kindly share sample data, with expected output

Comment: well, `groupby` IS the efficient approach, if used properly

Comment: your problem is the lambda  which will be slow, you can re-create your data model to avoid it, but need to see your data first.

Comment: I've added example data to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[df['TIME'] - df['ID'].map(df.groupby('ID').TIME.first()) > pd.Timedelta(days=DAYS)]
```

Comment: Brilliant! About twice as fast when tested on the example code in the question. Thanks mate. I think you meant `<` rather than `>` though XD